# ObservableCollection не обновляется в DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Споткнулся на обновлении DataGrid при добавлении элемента в ObservableCollection.
Есть некий класс *Material*:

```
 public class Material : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {  
     public string Type
     {
        get { return type; }
        set { type = value; OnPropertyChanged("Type"); 
     }
   }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

В VM создаю экземпляр класса и несколько методов для работы с ним.

```
public class Window_с : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
    ObservableCollection<Material> furniture;
    public ObservableCollection<Material> Furniture
    {
        get { return furniture; }
        set {
            furniture = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Furniture");
        }
    }
    public Window_с()
    {
     furniture = new ObservableCollection<Material>();
    }

      public void SetFurniture()
     {               
                Material tmp = new Material();                     
                Furniture.Add(tmp);
     }
       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }

}
```

В XAML делаю привязку:

```
<Grid>
       <DataGrid Name="CalculateGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding 
Window_Client.Furniture, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"   />
</Grid>
```

В приложении есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую открывается *CalculateWindow* с *CalculateGrid*, но при добавлении или изменении коллекции, *Grid* обновляется только при повторном открытии *CalculateWindow*. 
При попытке изменить коллекцию, состояние так же не сохраняется.
При отладке, программа даже не пытается попасть в

```
    set {
            furniture = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Furniture");
        }
```

upd:

В программе есть главное окно, в котором задаются размеры:

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new VM();
    }

private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                CalculateWindow f = new CalculateWindow ();
                f.DataContext = DataContext;
                f.Show();          
        }
```

и окно с расчетом.

```
  public partial class CalculateWindow : Window
    {
        public CalculateWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();              
        }
    }
```

В *VM()*

```
class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public RelayCommand CalculateWindow => new RelayCommand(o =>
        {
            Window_Client = new Window_с();
            CalculateWindows();
        });

        Window_с window;

        public Window_с Window_Client
        {
            get { return window; }
            set { window = value; OnPropertyChanged("window"); }
        }

        public void CalculateWindows()
        {
            Window_Client.SetFurniture(pList);
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ошибок биндинга в output нет?

Comment: Ошибок нет, он данные подтягивает, но только со второго нажатия. Я вызываю метод SetFurniture() при нажатии кнопки, открывается пустое окно. При повторном нажатии открывается окно с предыдущими данными.

Comment: в вашем коде нет ничего ни про какие окна, потому я не представляю, о чем вы вообще говорите.

Comment: первое, что бросилось в глаза - `set { window = value; OnPropertyChanged("window"); }` ===> `set { window = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Window_Client)); }`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Можете добавить ответом, закроем вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас неверно настроены нотификации об изменении свойства Window_Client

```
    public Window_с Window_Client
    {
        get { return window; }
        set { window = value; OnPropertyChanged("window"); }
    }
```

В метод `OnPropertyChanged` необходимо передавать название публичного свойства, а вы передаете название приватного поля. Должно быть вот так:

```
    public Window_с Window_Client
    {
        get { return window; }
        set { window = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Window_Client)); }
    }
```